# Sniff/Capture where windows hotkeys are coming from

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

There are some shortcut keys on my windows computer that must be coming from some program. I know that I've installed a couple of "productivity" programs, but for the life of me I can't figure out what's causing some of these shortcuts.

Is there a generic program/way for me to hit some hotkey, and then know where it's coming from? For example, suppose that I have an autohotkey exe running which always prints a message when I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>. Is there a way to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, and then know that the autohotkey program is binding that keystroke to something?

If there isn't an easy way to do this (I'm betting there's not), then what possible places are there to check? Are there known ways to bind hotkeys via registry? If so, are there common places in there? Are there keyboard settings in Windows OS somewhere?

I know this is an abstract and hard question, but I think it's very practical for "super users", has objectivity, and so belongs here.

Comment: btw, I finally figured out that I have VirtuaWin installed, so when I hit ctrl-alt-down, it was switching to a virtual desktop. At first I thought something closed all my programs, but when they all suddently "came back" again with ctrl-alt-up, that's when I figured it out. I know it's my fault for installing all these things, but I still think it's helpful to have a way to track them down if possible.